# Why Doesn't Anything Return When Calling the Print() from a Class?

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I'm trying to learn about OOP concepts in Python and have this dumb little script which I saw from a YouTube video.  This script should return "May name is Tom" however nothing returns when I execute it.

I'm sure i'm doing something very dumb, but can someone tell me why nothing prints out so that I can move forward and learn?  I'm not finding any answer anywhere online.

i've tried searching online but to no avail

```
class Robot:
    def __init__(self, n, c, w):
        self.name = n
        self.color = c
        self.weight = w

    def introduce_self(self):
        print("My name is " + self.name)


r1 = Robot("Tom", "red", 30)
```

Absolutely nothing is displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the following, you are creating an object of the class Robot.

```
r1 = Robot("Tom", "red", 30)
```

Unless you call the method of the class, the print statement wouldn't execute.
So, after creating the class object, do the following to invoke the `introduce_self()` method.

```
r1.introduce_self()
```

Comment: Uh....okay, that makes sense.  I knew I was missing something rather basic. But it's frustrating to watch or read tutorials and then scripts are incomplete.  

Thanks - i'll mark your answer as correct.